# enumerate second line problem

Tags: xetex, enumerate

I am new TeX user.
I use enumerate. output it like in attach file in number 1.



 `1. XXXXX 
     (a) YYYYYYYYYY
         YYYYYYYYYY`

but i need output like number 2.

`1. XXXXX
     (a) YYYYYYYYYY
  YYYYYYYYYY`

How I can do.

Thank you very much.

[image: attach file]

Comment: Don't use enumerate for the last (a) step.  Just set \parindent and \parskip and use normal paragraphs (possibly inside a minipage of width \textwidth).

Comment: Can you post a small document showing the code you used to achieve your first sample? If you use the `enumitem` package, you can set the margins as in your second sample quite easily.

Comment: Thank you very much. I use `enumitem` and use `\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=-5mm,itemindent=3em]`. It look very nice.

Comment: @HarishKumar Can you turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks for pinging. I have added the answer. :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please also read: [How do you accept an answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `enumitem` for all your list needs. For this particular need, you need to use

```
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0pt,itemindent=2em]
```

Adjust the values appropriately.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{kantlipsum,showframe}   %% just for this example
\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0pt,itemindent=2em]
    \item \kant[1]
    \item \kant[2]
  \end{enumerate}
  Some text
\end{document}
```

[image]